# Can the cube of 2 different complex numbers be the same?

Tags: complex-numbers

Can the cube of 2 different complex numbers be the same?

I think it cannot be the same, but I don't really know how to prove it. I tried to expand it but it gives a very ugly result.

Comment: What about the third root of unity $\omega$, and $\omega^2$? That is $\omega=e^{\frac{2}{3}\pi i}$ and $\omega^2=e^{\frac{4}{3}\pi i}$.

Comment: What's a complex "vector" and how would you cube one?

Comment: @ErickWong sorry typo

Comment: @PeterWoolfitt, perhaps easier to write $\omega$ out as $-1/2 +\sqrt{-3}/2$

Answer (score 3):

If you take $x,y\in\mathbb{C}$ and $x^3=y^3$, we get $$
x^3-y^3=(x-y)(x^2+xy+y^2)=0 \Rightarrow x=y , x^2+y^2+xy=0
$$
Solving the second equation you get $y=\omega x$ or $y=\omega^2 x$.
You can check $y^3=\omega^3x^3=x^3$ etc.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have to ask, you are yet to study [De Moivre's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre's_formula) (in particular, see the applications section). For any complex number $z_1$ and integer $n$, you can find $n-1$ other complex numbers $\{z_2, z_3, \ldots , z_n\}$ that will all have the same $n$-th power as $z_1$ (also, the same absolute value). Pretty neat, eh?

Also, if you try plotting those numbers in the complex plane, they will all be be on a circle with a radius equal to the absolute value of any of those complex numbers. Complex numbers are cool.